# Result of the limit n -> infinity x(ln(x/x+1)

Tags: system-limitations

Can someone give me a detailed, step by step process on how to solve:

$\lim_{x\to \infty } x(ln$$ \frac{x}{x+1}) $

Comment: This site is about the software *Mathematica*, maybe you should ask here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mattiav27sorry, I'm new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WolframAlpha["Limit of (x Log[x/(x+1)]) for x approaching Infinity"]
```

[image]